# Google script - Show specific sheet to users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Script that allows a user to navigate through a spreadsheet thanks to images with a script assigned to them. However, since a few days, the function isn't working properly. Said function :

```
function switchToDowntime() {
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet("SHEET HERE")
}
```

where `spreadsheet` is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`

This function used to work, I believe. Now, it just runs and does nothing. Doesn't change the current range, or display the right sheet. If anyone could help, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will switch to a named sheet:

```
function switchToSheet(sheetName) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
}
```

I think you are missing the first line where you get the spreadsheet object by calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

Also, note that the `setActiveSheet` function takes a `Sheet` object rather than the name of the `Sheet` so you need to call `getSheetByName("SHEET HERE")`.

Comment: Hello Aidan, I did forget to add in my example that the spreadsheet var already gets the active spreadsheet, will edit OP to reflect it.

Comment: Updated to include the getSheetByName("SHEET HERE"), can't believe I missed this... However, still not working.